# Nested if condition Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my default cell value is zero that value look up with other sheet cell Reference.

all there cell match with other sheet reference.

```
J2=J3+J4

=IF(J2=J3+J4, "SUCCESS", 
 IF(J2=J3=J4="0", "WAITING FOR VALUE",  
 IF(J2=" "&J3=" "&J4=" ", " ", "UNSUCCESS")))
```

so by default all the cell value is cell i added the above formula but its not showing the if value is zero "waiting for value"

Comment: Should be `IF(AND(J2=0,J3=0,J4=0), ...` and `IF(AND(J2=" ",J3=" ",J4=" "), ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(J2=J3+J4, J2<>0, J3<>"", J4<>""), "SUCCESS", 
 IF(OR(J2=0, J3=0, J4=0), "WAITING FOR VALUE", "UNSUCCESS"))
```

please check this answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

### Nested IF Statements

- If all are blank or `Nothing` then `Nothing` (`""`).
- If any evaluates to zero (blank or 0) then `"WAITING FOR VALUE"`.
- If the expression evaluates to `TRUE` then `"SUCCESS"`.
- Otherwise, `"UNSUCCESS"`.
- Note the importance of the order of the statements. Consider the following:

  - If all are blank or zero, the expression also evaluates to `TRUE`.
  - If e.g. cell `J2` is blank then `J2=0` evaluates to `TRUE`.

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(J2:J4)=3,"",
    IF(OR(J2=0,J3=0,J4=0),"WAITING FOR VALUE",
    IF(J2=J3+J4,"SUCCESS","UNSUCCESS")))
```